# Is the following inequality derivation logically valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

**PROBLEM**

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a function.

> Derive an upper bound for
>   $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a},$$
>   given that
>   $$a < b$$
>   $$a < b \implies \frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{f(a)}{a}=\frac{f(a)}{b}<\frac{f(b)}{a}=\frac{b}{a}\cdot\frac{f(b)}{b}$$
>   and
>   $$\frac{f(b)/b}{f(a)/a}<2.$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $a < b$ is true, and since
$$a < b \implies \frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{f(a)}{a}=\frac{f(a)}{b}<\frac{f(b)}{a}=\frac{b}{a}\cdot\frac{f(b)}{b} \implies \bigg(\frac{a}{b}\bigg)^2 < \frac{f(b)/b}{f(a)/a} < 2,$$
we obtain (trivially),
$$\frac{a}{b} < \sqrt{2}.$$
Therefore (*and here is the gray area for me*),
$$\sqrt\frac{a}{b}-\sqrt\frac{b}{a} < \sqrt[4]{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2}}.$$
Squaring both sides of the last inequality and simplifying, we get
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}<\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 2.12132.$$

**QUESTION**

> *Is the derivation of the inequalities in this post logically valid?*

Comment: What is $f(a)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, you can take it to be the classical sum of divisors.  That is, $f(a) = \sigma(a) = \sigma_{1}(a)$.

Comment: I think you mean to ask is it sound, valid arguments don't always give sound conclusions. https://www.khanacademy.org/partner-content/wi-phi/wiphi-critical-thinking

Comment: I could not find any mistake.

Comment: It'd be better to state that "$f$ is a function *such that* $\frac {f(b)}a < \frac {f(a)}b$ and $\frac {f(b)/b}{f(a)/a} < 2$ whenever $a< b$".  The way you stated it with the pertainent *premise* conditions buried deep in a calculation you, it appears you are trying to make a statement that is true for all functions, which it obviously isn't.

Comment: Also the way you state it "Find and upper bound for $\frac ab + \frac ba$" is "there is none".  If $b=1$ and then for any $a > M$ $\frac ab + \frac ba = a + \frac 1a > a > M$.  As $f$ is not stated anywhere in what you wish be prove, $f$ being a function with a condition is no more relevent than Babar being the king of the elephants.  I assume that *isn't* the upper bound you want to find but I don't know what upper bound you *do* want to find.  the upper bound (if any) of $f$?  If so, what does the expression $\frac ab + \frac ba$ have to do with anything.

Comment: Oh, wait.  So those are conditions based on the values of $a$ and $b$???  $a$ and $b$ are not free to be any values but must satisfy the condition?????  Which are as equally about acceptable values of $a$ and $b$ than they are about charateristics of $f$?   ... THis is *very* weirdly stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the mistake in my original argument:

Suppose I have a sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$, and $\frac{a}{b} < \varepsilon$.

Then $\varepsilon^{-1}$ is sufficiently large, so that
$$\frac{a}{b} < \varepsilon < \varepsilon^{-1} < \frac{b}{a}.$$

Consider the product
$$\bigg(\frac{a}{b} - \varepsilon\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{b}{a} - \varepsilon\bigg)$$
which is negative.

Therefore,
$$\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{b}{a} + \varepsilon^2 < \varepsilon\cdot\bigg(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\bigg) \implies \varepsilon^{-1} + \varepsilon < \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}.$$

In general, the function
$$f(z) := z + \frac{1}{z}$$
is not bounded from above.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

Since $a < b$, then
$$\sqrt\frac{a}{b}<1$$
and
$$\sqrt\frac{b}{a}>1$$
so that
$$\sqrt\frac{a}{b}-\sqrt\frac{b}{a}<0.$$
Proceeding similarly as in the original argument, squaring both sides, we obtain
$$\bigg(\sqrt\frac{a}{b}-\sqrt\frac{b}{a}\bigg)^2 = \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-2<0,$$
which would violate the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality.

**NOTE THAT THE SQUARE OF A NEGATIVE NUMBER SHOULD BE POSITIVE.**